# Unable to select the correct dropdownlist.selectedItem.text from a dropdownlist populated by a datatable

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, datatable

I've been trying for two days to understand why this error and nothing I do helps me get an answer.

It turns out that I have a form in which there are two controls type dropdownlist each one of them populates through a method that connects to a database and executes a query to pull the data.

This method stores the data in a datatable later to fill the dropdownlist using the following code:

```
DataTable dt = PartStoreAdministrativeTools.BS.SELECTS.Instance.LoadProcess ();

DdlHeaderProcess.DataSource = dt;

DdlHeaderProcess.DataTextField = "Process";

DdlHeaderProcess.DataValueField = "ID";

DdlHeaderProcess.DataBind ();
```

then there is a button that when the user clicks on it he should capture the option selected for that I use the following code in the click event of the button:

```
string val = DdlHeaderProcess.SelectedItem.Text;
```

Now the problem is that when I click on the button, it selects item # 1 from the list even if the user has selected another

If you need more info in order to have a clearer view let me know please.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not loading data into the dropdowns on every page-load.

```
// load dropdowns on first page-load only.
if(!IsPostBack)
{
    // load dropdowns.
}
```